# What is correct - "En 1871 otras más constituciones *fue escrito* vs *fueron escritos*"

Tags: concordancia-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

I encountered the original sentence like this:

> En 1871 otras más constituciones **fue escrito**.

I actually started learning topic of 'concordancia' and grasped main things, but need to internalize.

In this particular case am I correct to say that sentence below is also correct?

> En 1871 otras más constituciones **fueron escritos**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct sentence is:

> En 1871 otras más constituciones fueron escritas

*Constituciones* is a feminine noun, subject of the sentence in this case.

*Fue* is the third-person singular preterite indicative form of *ser*, but *constituciones* is not in the singular, but in the **plural**, so the correct thing is to use *fueron*, third-person plural preterite indicative form of *ser*. The same applies to the verb *escrito*, which is in the singular and must also be in the plural (*escritos*).

On the other hand, since *constituciones* is a feminine noun, *escritos* must also be in feminine form (*escritas*).